# Identify Character Set of table data

Tags: mysql, sql, database, datatable, vertica

Actually I am trying to find the character set of data which is in database table and the database is HP Vertica. I am using AES Encryption and after this encryption I am not able to identify character set of table data.

Comment: Please include some sample data if possible.

Comment: yeah sure, But data is in encrypted form like this "02���wʙ����?ߖ"

Comment: Can't you try decrypting different ways until you get something other than gibberish?

Comment: Actuallly i am reading a AES encrypted column from my source and type of column is nvarchar so when we start our jobin datastage and read data from source. The job run Successfully and exactly same data is moved to my target data base with same column type.

And the Problem Actually occur is that when i query the data to check whether the my source and target values are same, the query does not show any result and visually if we look source,target value they are same value but sql statement return nothing and the database is Vertica.

Comment: Then you should AES decrypt this data; I don't see any other way _unless_, for example, you just wanted to compare two encrypted strings against each other.  Then you wouldn't need to decrypt.

Comment: I am using AES decrypt with key on my target database data but it dd not do decryption instead giving me error . There is UTF8 function in vertica to check whether the column data is UTF8 or not. So my source data is not UTF8 and after passing data through datastage tool to target database which also vertica get converted into UTF8 so my question is that how i can identify the character set of my source and do same conversion in datastage

Comment: What is your end goal here?  Do you need to use that decrypted data?

Comment: my end Goal is that the data must be match in my source and target column value after transfer of data through datastage

Comment: SELECT  *
FROM SOURCE A
INNER JOIN TARGET B
ON A.id=B.id                                                                                               THIS query has to work but its not working and when we look values they look same

Comment: I do hope you're trying to encrypt/decrypt a VARBINARY column... isn't it? Also, as you might know, one thing is the encoding and a totally different thing is the character set. Finally... How data is loaded?

Comment: encrypt/decrypt Column is varchar and data is loaded with datastage tool without any transformation in data!!

Comment: Varchar?? How can you be sure that AES encrypted test is encoded UTF8? I guess you know that VARCHARs HAVE to be encoded UTF8... isn't it?

Comment: yes it has to be in UTF8 but i dnt know the character set of AES encrypted column

Comment: Again... character set is one thing and encoding is a different thing. Aes does not produce utf8 encoding in output so... you cannot save it into varchar columns. Use varbnary...

Comment: Actually i am using AES Encryption in vertica and i have read the documentation of that plugin which says that AES encrption value will store in varchar column